# Prevent BitmapDecoder use from causing SystemOutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, wpf, out-of-memory, imagesource

I am developing a scientific image-capture application where successive webcam frames are saved as individual images (as opposed to video encoding).

Files are saved to a zip archive, and when the capture is loaded for analysis, each time the frame at a given position is queried, a `BitmapFrame` is generated by the method `LoadImage()` in the following class:

```
public class ImagemCinemetria
{
    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; private set; }

    public BitmapSource Imagem
    {
        get
        {
            if (_imagem == null)
                _imagem = LoadImage();
            return _imagem;
        }
    }
    BitmapSource _imagem;


    // CONSTRUTOR
    public ImagemCinemetria(int index, byte[] jpegBytes)
    {
        Index = index;
        ImageBytes = jpegBytes;
    }



    private BitmapSource LoadImage()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(ImageBytes))
        {
            var decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            return decoder.Frames.First();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, as soon as I start to navigate the capture (by moving a slider cursor similar to a video player) and the `BitmapFrames` start to be loaded, there is a HUGE memory consumption and quite soon I get a `SystemOutOfMemoryException`.

I know vaguely that there are some cache options for WPF bitmaps, but I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up finding a solution myself.

Whatever the reason why `JpegBitmapDecoder` is occupying so much memory, the actual problem is that the property `Imagem` *stays* referenced in memory for all the class lifetime.

I got rid of the `OutOfMemoryException` by replacing the lazy-loading by a property getter that creates the `BitmapFrame` *de novo* each time it is called:

So instead of

```
public BitmapSource Imagem
{
    get
    {
        if (_imagem == null)
            _imagem = LoadImage();
        return _imagem;
    }
}
BitmapSource _imagem;
```

Now I have

```
public BitmapSource Imagem => LoadImage();
```